# Is it always possible to write the state corresponding to a set of stabilizer generators?

Tags: quantum-state, stabilizer-code, stabilizer-state

Given a set of stabilizer generators, is it always possible to write down the state corresponding to it? Is there a way to write down the quantum state corresponding to a stabilizer generator?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given an $n$-qubit system and $n$ generators $g_i$ (which commute and square to identity), then the state that you are after satisfies
$$
g_i|\psi\rangle=|\psi\rangle.
$$
(This defines it uniquely, up to a global phase and normalisation.)
One straightforward way to construct this directly is just
$$
|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|=\frac{1}{2^n}\prod_i(I+g_i).
$$
Thus, you can compute the matrix using the $\{g_i\}$ and find the vector $|\psi\rangle$ by determining the one eigenvector that does not have 0 eigenvalue. In practice, you can do this simply by reading off any non-trivial column of the matrix, and normalising.

For example, let $n=2$ and take
$$
g_1=X\otimes X,\qquad g_2=Z\otimes Z.
$$
We have
$$
|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|=\frac14(I+XX)(I+ZZ)=\frac14(I+XX+ZZ-YY).
$$
If I read off the first column, this is equivalent to computing
$$
|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|00\rangle=\frac14(I+XX+ZZ-YY)|00\rangle=\frac12(|00\rangle+|11\rangle).
$$
Thus,
$$
|\psi\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|00\rangle+|11\rangle).
$$

Answer (score 2):

You can do this easily using Qiskit as follows:

```python
from qiskit.quantum_info import StabilizerState, Statevector
 
stabilizer_list = ["XX", "ZZ"]
stabilizer_state = StabilizerState.from_stabilizer_list(stabilizer_list)
sv = Statevector.from_label('0'*stabilizer_state.num_qubits).evolve(stabilizer_state)
sv.draw('latex')
```

The result:
$$\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} |00\rangle+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} |11\rangle$$